# Is Sitecore Connect customizable?

Tags: sitecore, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am sitting with a project where I need to do a 2-way synchronize between Sitecore 8.2 and Microsoft Dynamics 365. From what I have been able to find, I see that version 1.4.1 can connect the following out of the box.

-Campaigns
-Contacts
-Marketing lists

I need to synchronize far more than that, and I am curious about whether or not Sitecore Connect is customizable to synchronize with everything there is in Dynamics 365. I have read all the documentation I could find, without finding an answer.

There is also the option of upgrading to sitecore 9, and using Dynamics CRM Connect 2.x. But again, I can't find much documentation about the possibilities of 2.x

Is Sitecore Connect 1.4.x/2.x customizable to a point where you can synchronize everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can customize what data is being sent back and forth. Some example mappings are shown in the documentation for 2.0.1: http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v2.0.1/adding-custom-data/dynamics-to-sitecore/custom-contact-facets/index.html

For v1.4.1, you can check the documentation for additional CRM entities: http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v1.4.1/cookbooks/supporting-additional-crm-entities/index.html

Ultimately, this is all based on the Data Exchange Framework which is a fully customizable connection framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response! :)